# Detecting OnClick events on already selected tab in taBHost to perform a operation like a flip flop nature

Tags: java, android

**Here below i have three tabs, Each tab will take you to a activity**

- **Click on** `Rating` - - - > `MainActivity.class`
- **Click on** `Price` - - - > `PriceDescriptionActivity.class`
- **Click on** `Distance`- - - > `DistanceDiscriptionActivity.class`

---

**How can i make such that::**

- **Click on** `Rating` - - - > `MainActivity.class`
- **Click on** `Rating` for second time - - - > `PriceDescriptionActivity.class`
- **Click on** `Rating` for third time - - - > `MainActivity.class`

---

**AndroidTabRestaurantDescListView.java**

```
public class AndroidTabRestaurantDescListView extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Rating";
    private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Price";
    private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Distance";

    Button Photos;
    Button Filter;
    Button Search;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Photos=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PhotoButton); 
        Filter=(Button) findViewById(R.id.FilterButton);
        Search=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SearchBottomBarID);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Inbox Tab
        TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);
        // Tab Content
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

        // Outbox Tab
        TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
        Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, PriceDescriptionActivity.class);
        PriceSpec .setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC);
        PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);

        // Profile Tab
        TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
        Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, DistanceDiscriptionActivity.class);
        DistanceSpec .setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC); 
        DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(DistanceSpec); 

        //Set the current value tab to default first tab
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);




    }

}
```

---

**Say i don't want to use fragments, Or custom buttons .... How can i achieve that here**

**Is it possible**

**If possible ----- what changes should i need to make ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to detect if the same tab is selected for the second time :

```
// Add this to the class
private static int count=0;

// Adding listener for Getting Same Tab selected
    int numberOfTabs = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++) {
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setTag(i + "");
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                int previousTab = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
                int currentTab = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
                    if (previousTab == currentTab) {
                        if (currentTab == 0) {
                            count++;
                            if(count == 1)
                                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                            else {
                                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                                count = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else
                        count =0;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to use a counter to count the no.of times the Tab is selected. Then perform accordingly.

Comment: I have added the solution for the first tab, rest you can do as per your need

Comment: [+1 for edit ] .... One more question :: Its navigating between tabs right ? ..... like first one and second .... i am looking to navigating between activities .... MainActivity.class & ... PriceDescriptionActivity.class ...using onetab itself... Were u able u analyze my question ....

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you want to do here. But the standard should be switching to the particular tab only when the tab is selected & not to navigate from one tab to another on selecting the same tab.

Comment: Yes .... Reason i want this is ... click it once sort the items in activity ... click on it again .... reverse sorting ... so .... to get that requirement my proposed question becomes crucial .. part.... i have the sorting logic ready .... only switching in already selected tab ... i am not able to do !

Comment: i think the latest code would help your in switching your tabs dynamically